# Rearrangement of formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been out of education for nearly 20 years. Just looking for some help. Pretty basic stuff. Trying to transpose some equations and looking for some conformation and or corrections where I am going wrong. This is what I have done so far. Is anyone able to check it for me. Also apologies if I have used the wrong tag I cannot remember what subset of mathematics this falls under.

$\mathbf W= \frac {1}{2} CV^2$

make $\mathbf V$ as the subject

**Step 1:**
Remove the fraction my multiplying by 2

$\mathbf 2(W) = CV^2$

**Step 2:**
Isolate $\mathbf V^2$ from  $\mathbf C$ by division

$\frac{\mathbf2(W)}{\mathbf C} = V^2$

**Step 3:** Remove the square by doing square root.

$\sqrt\frac{\mathbf2(W)}{\mathbf C} = V$

Therefore

$V = \sqrt\frac{\mathbf2(W)}{\mathbf C}$

Comment: @projectilemotion Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine, except you should have a $\pm$ when doing this step:
$$V^2=\frac{2W}{C} \implies V=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2W}{C}}$$

---

Here is an example showing why:

Suppose we have:
$$x^2=16$$
The solutions to $x$ can be both positive or negative:
$$x=-4 \text{   or   } x=4$$
If we substitute both these solutions in the original equation, the left hand side and right hand side are both equal:
$$(-4)^2=16$$
$$4^2=16$$

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Great to see the explanation for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct.

However note that in taking the square root you really generate 2 solutions i.e. $\pm$ what you have.

An example would be if $$x^2=4$$ then $$x=\pm 2$$.

This $\pm$ may or may not be important in the context of your problem.

Comment: Well all the material I use makes no mention of it however it is pretty basic stuff. Perhaps something I will look into it. Does it have a name. Something I could reference in looking it up?

Comment: Maybe look at quadratic equations. There is a formula for their solution where this +/- also appears for the same reason.